# How do I add a button to a tpl

Tags: event-handling, sencha-touch, task-parallel-library

I'm not sure if this is possible but I have an app that isn't doing what I want. First it displays a list of restaurants from a database into a panel.

```
tpl: [
   '<tpl for=".">',
       '<div="my_div"><h2>{restaurant_name}</h2></div>',
   '</tpl>'
]
```

this works properly and gives me a list of my restaurants. Now comes the question. I want to add a button so I have "my_div" click to another panel. I can do this with a docked item but this idea won't work since you can click any restaurant and get their info.

I assume I would need to somehow call an event handler (which I can get working from a docked item). I'm basically stuck on how to add a button to a template, and the sencha help is useless on this topic.

I have event handlers that look like this:

```
var restaurantListHandler = function(button,event){
    mainPanel.setActiveItem(restaurantList, {type: 'slide', direction: 'right'});
}
```

Thanks

Eric

Answer (score 2):

If I understand you correctly, you're looking for:

1. a button to be added to your template
2. an event handler to be bound to that button that is different than the one your other list items are bound to
3. the button must be within the list itself; it can't be a separate piece
4. the button's event handler must route it to a new page, rather than the action of the other list items which are its siblings

Is all of this true?

If yes, I'd throw a condition into your list event handler that will check for a class or ID on the element (whichever is easiest/most lightweight) and upon finding it, have it take a different action, *e.g.*, go to your next page. Kind of like jQuery.live() or other delegates. Let me know if you need me to elaborate.

If no, I'd say have a look at my number 3; does the button absolutely have to be within the list? If it's associated with each item then we would do one thing, but if not, we would want to do another. So I need to know that first and foremost before I can fully answer. If it does have to be in there, see above. If it doesn't have to be in the list, then I would take it out of the list and declare it as a new component. From there you should be able to specify a handler in the config, like

```
items: { xtype: 'button', handler: goAwesomePlaces }
```

where `goAwesomePlaces` is your handler.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the option onItemDisclosure of Ext.List:

http://docs.sencha.com/touch/1-1/#!/api/Ext.List-cfg-onItemDisclosure

A demo is at the Sencha Touch Kitchen Sink under User Interface / List / Disclosure:

http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/touch/examples/kitchensink/

```
var serviceList = new Ext.List({
            id: 'servicelist',
            blockRefresh: true,
            pinHeaders: false,
            itemTpl: serviceTemplate,
            grouped: true,
            indexBar: false,
            singleSelect: true,
            allowDeselect: false,
            showAnimation: 'slide',
            store: serviceStore,
            emptyText: L10N[lang].msg.no_services,
            multiSelect: false,
            itemCls: 'servicemain',
            cls: 'background',
            onItemDisclosure: function(record, btn, index) {
          Ext.Msg.alert('Service', 'Name: ' + record.get('service'), Ext.emptyFn);
      }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

If you wish for something like:
A list with a button on each item. then here is my implementation of the same

```
var asListItemTpl = new Ext.XTemplate(
                              '<tpl for=".">',
                              '<div class="sb-section-title">{label}</div>',
                              '<div class="as-button"><input type="button" id="btn{id}" value="btn{id}" width="12px"> </div>',
                              '</tpl>'
                              );
```

Hope this makes sense.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you can use something like:

```
onclick="javascript:selectRestaurant(\'{Id}\');"
```

on the div or (what I once did) on an image and have a global function `selectRestaurant`.
`Id` would then be a database field that uniquely identifies the restaurant.

Comment: -1 for the missuse of goto-markers (`javascript:`) and using obtrusive js.